# Oh who wrote the leftmost part?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Oh who wrote the leftmost part?
>   Results in tripping if you add its start
>   Ecoutez: a clue you'll find
>   Let's entangle yet unwind
>   On the twelfth a party too
>   Bread if you make me a stew

So who am I? And explain each line ...

Comment: I'm predicting this will last no longer than 30 minutes

Comment: [Prediction was right.](/a/42930/12114)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> RAVEL.

I got this because

> the first letter of each line gives a sequence which when read backwards becomes [BOLERO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bol%C3%A9ro), a piece of music by [Maurice Ravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Ravel).

*Oh who wrote the leftmost part?*

> As I said, look at the leftmost character of each line.

*Results in tripping if you add its start*

> Add a T to RAVEL to get TRAVEL, which is what one does when [tripping](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tripping) (going on trips).

*Ecoutez: a clue you'll find*

> "Ecoutez" is French for "listen", and you can certainly listen to music. And Ravel was French.

*Let's entangle yet unwind*

> [Ravel](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ravel) can mean either to tangle or to untangle; it's a Conflicted Word™.

*On the twelfth a party too*

> RAVEL = RAVE (party) + L (the twelfth letter of the alphabet).

*Bread if you make me a stew*

> An anagram or 'stew' of RAVEL is LAVER, which [can be used to make bread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laver_(seaweed)#Laverbread). (Thanks to **@paolo** for getting this!)

Comment: You might want to try explaining each line.

Comment: Also, *ecoutez* is a French word meaning *listen*. Maurice Ravel was French.

Comment: @IAmInPLS Already added that :-)

Comment: one could experience tripping at a RAVE party

Comment: "Bread if you make me a stew": an anagram (or "stew") of RAVEL is LAVER, which is a kind of seaweed that can be used to make a type of bread (laver bread).

Comment: @abligh Got a possible explanation for each line now (the one I'm least sure about is the 5th).

Comment: @randal'thor - all correct bar the fifth. Someone in the comments is a big fat clue to how that works, but perhaps not obviously associated with that line.

Comment: RAVEL = RAVE + L and L is the twelfth letter.

Comment: @abligh Got it! Nice one.

Comment: @Gareth Hadn't seen your comment when I edited :-)

Comment: I guessed that, given how short the interval was.

Comment: @randal'thor - indeed - accepted

Comment: Why is anagram a stew?

Comment: @zespri Because you mix lots of different things together to make a stew? In cryptic crosswords, anagrams can be indicated by all sorts of different words or metaphors.

Comment: Actually you missed part of clue 5 - Ravel was French. Added it via edit.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming the answer is:

> [Maurice Ravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Ravel)

Because:

> The first letters of the riddle backwards spell "Bolero". [Boléro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bol%C3%A9ro) is a one-movement orchestral piece by the French composer Maurice Ravel.

Oh who wrote the leftmost part?

> Who wrote the leftmost part - as in who wrote what is formed by the leftmost letters in the riddle - i.e. Bolero.

Results in tripping if you add its start

> Not sure

Ecoutez: a clue you'll find

> Ecoutez is a French word - referring to the French origin of the composer

Let's entangle yet unwind

> 

On the twelfth a party too

> Perhaps refers to the musical instruments used in the 12th part somehow?

Bread if you make me a stew

> No idea.

Comment: You might want to try explaining each line.

Comment: I upvoted this, but accepted @randal'thor 's answer as (s)he got all the explanations first.

Comment: "(s)he", well... rand al'thor must answer this puzzle first :)